# Mkbibquote and printtext add extra space in quotation marks

Tags: spacing, biblatex, biber

As title, if I declare a bibliography field format with printtex and mkbibquote, latex adds an extra space after the first quotation mark, while it doesn't if I don't use \printtext.

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@inreference{treccani:spettrofotometro,
    title = {spettrofotometro},
    booktitle = {La piccola Treccani},
    volume = {XI},
    publisher = {Istituto enciclopedia italiana},
    date = {1997}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{\printtext{s.v.}\addspace\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\begin{document}

This is just an example\footfullcite{treccani:spettrofotometro}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `\printtext` within `\DeclareFieldFormat`, it serves no additional purpose here and confuses the punctuation tracker, just go with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inreference]{title}{s\adddot v\adddotspace\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

In general, the output defined in `\DeclareFieldFormat` will only be printed if the field is non-empty anyway and printing will start `biblatex`'s punctuation handler. As such you won't need `\printtext` to take care of punctuation handling. In fact it can have adverse effects if you use it, because you essentially 'nest' the punctuation tracker and confuse it.